# Highlight text by keywords which are separated by comma

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to split up text by comma - i.e. keywords are as the following:

```
keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, keyword4
```

How can I have a the black style element for each and every keyword that is separated by a comma. Is there an easy way to do this? The text is always dynamic, so I never know exactly what those keywords will be and how many. So each keyword should have a box elements around it.

```
<span class="keyword-option-black">keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, keyword4</span>

.keyword-option-black {
    color:white;
    background-size:contain;
    margin:10px;
    padding:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background:black;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand this part: `split up text by comma` what do you mean by that?

Comment: maybe you should look at how those keyword are inserted in HTML (php, js, .. ? ) and wrap them in a tag meanwhile

Comment: Keywords are dynamic - i.e. python but looking for a simple way of doing it and wondered if there was any CSS display way of doing it that doesn't occlude what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Django, I did it the following way.

1. Create a simple CSS class to perform the highlighting.
2. Create a custom tag that splits up data in template view into `<span class="keyword">A</span><span class="keyword">B</span>`. It takes the original view output and parses this into a format that already has the spans included.

Answer (score 1):

CSS is unable to select text.

In order to highlight the keywords on a page, you need to use programming languages such as JavaScript *(for client-side)* or PHP *(or whatever else for server-side)* to wrap the keywords by a wrapper element which has a special CSS style to distinguish the keys.

Here, I implemented the above approach by using jQuery (just to demonstrate):

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/6faEr/)**

**JS part:**

```javascript
// Insert the keywords here,
// you can also get the keys automatically from the DOM if needed
var keywords = ['Google', 'Facebook', 'Social'];

$.each(keywords, function(index, key) {
    var $content = $('#content'),
        text = $content.html();

    $content.html(
        text.replace(
            new RegExp("("+ key +")", 'ig'), "<span class='highlight'>$1</span>"
        )
    );
});
```

And here is the `highlight` class:

```css
.highlight {
    color: white;
    background-size: contain;
    margin:10px;
    padding:5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML and CSS are static. Since you don't know how many keywords are gonna be there, you need something dynamic. Depending on implementation, you can use JavaScript or any Back-end language you are using.
Basically, you want to add a span tag around each keyword and style that span (span in one with class keyword-option-black). So, when you enter keywords to HTML use `<span>keywordX</span>` in loop that adds elements or, alternatively, add those tags when document loads using JavaScript.
Hope this helps.