# Javascript HTML keyword highlight

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div id="abc">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy class highlight text class that needs to be highlighted.
</div>
```

I want to highlight the words: "class highlight" and "class"

```
var words = ["class highlight", "class"];
var replace = '<span class="highlight-text">$1</span>';
var x = document.getElementById("abc").innerHtml;

for(var i = 0; i<words.length; i++){
    document.getElementById("abc").innerHtml.replace(pattern, replace);
}
```

The problem is that the first time, it replaces properly. But the second time, it spits out the HTML as well and highlights that. I understand why this is happening but what would be a fix to it.

EDIT:
Sorry, I forgot to include: pattern = words[i]

Comment: Similar topic: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21222339/1725764

Comment: The code as you posted it makes no sense.  What's `pattern`, and what does it have to do with `words.length`?  There should be a way you can do this without looping, and thereby resolve your problem.

Comment: In jQuery you could use .text() instead of innerHTML where you get the string

Comment: You're also not assigning the result of `replace` to anything.

Comment: Because matching HTML with regular expressions is a bad idea.

Comment: I think people are missing the real problem here: He has multiple words he's trying to highlight (hence the loop), but the second word is "class" which causes the "class" in the previous highlight replacement text ("<span class=...") to be replaced, resulting in broken HTML.

Answer (score 0):

This would work better:

```
var words = ["class highlight", "class"];
var replace = '<span class="highlight-text">$1</span>';
var x = document.getElementById("abc").innerHtml;

for(var i = 0; i<words.length; i++){
    var rpl = replace.replace('$1', words[i]);
    document.getElementById("abc").innerHtml.replace(words[i], rpl);
}
```

Comment: This won't work. The problem he's addressing is the second time he runs the code, it replaces the content inside the html tag as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
var words = [ "class", "class highlight"];

//replace reg exp will be in 3 parts
var replace = '$1<span class="highlight-text">$2</span>$3';

//need the longer words to appear before the smaller
words.sort(function(a,b){ return b.length>a.length; });  

//us an OR expression to replace the words
var re = new RegExp("([$\\s])(" + words.join("|") + ")([\\s^])","gi");


var elem = document.getElementById("abc");

//grab the text since matching on HTML is bad
var txt = elem.innerText || elem.textContent;

//make the new string
var replacedText = txt.replace(re, replace);

elem.innerHTML = replacedText;
```